# Should I pay off my HELOC or continue to save/invest?

Tags: heloc

I currently have a $560k mortgage and took out an additional $105k HELOC piggy back loan to make up the 20% needed for the Jumbo loan last year. I've been saving for the past year and a half and now have $100k in savings. Should I be paying down the HELOC early or investing/saving the money? the HELOC is variable with a current 5.95 APR

Comment: I'm closing as a duplicate, although I disagree with the accepted answer. I had given basically the same answer as the highest-voted answer but deleted it to close as a duplicate.  Pay off the HELOC as soon as you can, saving a little for an emergency fund if you wish.

Comment: I agree with D Stanley. I say pay off the HELOC and use it as your emergency fund until you have enough in cash. There's a small chance the HELOC could be taken away, but with good credit and good income I wouldn't be concerned about that.

Comment: This question was asked on the heels of two devastating hurricanes, which home owners discovered they have high deductibles, around 2% of home value.  For the OP, that would be at least 10K.  Many are struggling as they are over leveraged.  Pay off the HELOC and get an emergency fund.

Comment: another agreement. Get the HELOC out of your life ASAP. Debt is risk, and debt with a variable APR is playing with fire.